# i have to add prefix in some pages of my website and it show the conent of my existing page (mean without prefix page) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
$items =  array( 'page' ); 

foreach( $items as $item )
{
    add_filter( $item . '_link', 'my_link', 99, 2 );
}

function my_link($permalink, $post ) 
{   
     $pagearr = array('daily-dairy', 'free-downloads','latest-essay-topics','practice-           tests','practice-exercises','video-lectures','contacts','sample1','sample3');
     $arr = explode('/',$permalink);

     if(in_array($arr[sizeof($arr)-2],$pagearr)){
         $permalink = str_replace( get_site_url(), get_site_url() . '/institute',   $permalink );   
         return $permalink;
    }else{
         return $permalink;
    }   
}
```

This code adds a prefix in my page URL but it shows page not found when add the prefix. I have to show the content without the prefix page.

Comment: Add prefix in post slug instead of page url. It will work..

Comment: @ Hritik Pandey  Do you mean by permalink ? And  I tried to edit the permalink of the page and add prefix then it shows prefix with hyphen(-) with page slug

Answer (score 0):

you haven't mentioned here that which hook you are using for these functions, you have written in your code. Look at the code below and tell me if you find it working on your end.

```
function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){

    $post = get_post($id);

    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post' ||  $post->post_type == 'page'){
        return home_url('/YOUR_PREFIX/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }

    return $post_link;
} 
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer:- I was also tried this code but this add prefix my all pages but i have to add some list of pages. Thanks..

Comment: @kirti, You can add post ids in this function, according to your condition.